# Please help me find this manhwa ' Isekai' . I remember the FL , the og FL was not evil and everyone (all the male leads like her)

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, manga, reincarnation

The og FL has blonde hair or silver hair I don't remember and the FL has probably black hair or brown and something.
The FL knows the story flows from the novel and the og also knows it.
I don't remember the beginning of the story but there is a scene where the og FL was kidnapped by one of the male lead character's opposite party , an old evil duke man ( because he is the crown prince or someone with high status ) and actually the og FL and one of the ml i described like each other .she was thrown into a deep hole ( a well ?) near a graveyard ( or the place where all sinful bodies were thrown ) . One of the ml , the crown prince was anxious to the point he summons all his army to check the area and one of the other ml lead tried to calm him. The FL even helped with the searching.

Back to the og FL who was kidnapped, she believed that It would be late to find her when they managed to locate her location , she began saying all the things like how she was unable to confess or smthg and she was crying hard in the hole  ..

Skip to where they found her , she was found in a weak state.after that she was brought for treatment and later when the og FL has recovered. She went to meet with one of the ml to break up I guess because she didn't want to go through the situation again ( other reason would be he is someone high in status and she said he wont be able to protect her.. and after that I think th FL help the og FL to get back with one of the ml ... I don't know the rest

One thing I wanna point out is the story is actually quite similar with ' beware of the villainess' in terms of the number of male lead and how she was also the og FL in the story.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Do you remember any details about the setting or general synopsis? For example, are both of the FLs nobles? Are they both from another world, or is one a transmigrator and the other a regular reincarnator? Does anyone else reincarnate or transmigrate?

Comment: How is this SFF? This looks like *Beware of Villainess* manga.

Comment: @Satellite of Sin - The isekai/reincarnation aspect of the story automatically makes this fantasy, regardless of the rest of the plot. In this specific case, it sounds like the protagonist was someone from the real world who was reincarnated as a character within the world of a novel, which is a common premise in manhwa. We get numerous story-ID questions on this site involving that scenario or something similar.